# In MSAccess fetch same values together from 3 columns in a table and display

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am facing a problem matching values of column1 with column2 and column3. All I want is to display all the data from column1 with matching data infront of the matching values of column1. For Example:

```
 +----------------+--------------+
 |SB_AccNo        |CLAIM INITATED|
 +----------------+--------------+
 |122000031730    |1854.36       |
 |122000031730    |4172.31       |
 |122000031730    |5099.49       |
 |122000069210    |54.56         |
 |122000069210    |54.56         |
 |122000069210    |14998.50      |
 |122000069210    |27317.25      |
 +----------------+--------------+

 +---------------+---------------+
 |SB_AccNo1      |CLAIM INITATED1|
 +---------------+---------------+
 |122000031730   |1483.00        |
 |122000031730   |3338.00        |
 |122000031730   |4080.00        |
 |122000069210   |11999.00       |
 |122000069210   |21854.00       |
 |122000070281   |1091.00        |
 |122000070281   |1091.00        |
 +---------------+---------------+    

 +---------------+---------------+
 |SB_AccNo2      |CLAIM INITATED2|
 +---------------+---------------|
 |122000031730   |371.00         |
 |122000031730   |834.00         |
 |122000031730   |1019.00        |
 |122000069210   |3000.00        |
 |122000069210   |5463.00        |
 |122000070281   |273.00         |
 |122000070281   |273.00         |
 |122000070281   |954.00         |
 |122000070281   |3272.00        |
 +---------------+---------------+
```

I want to match the columns SB_AccNo,SB_AccNo1 and SB_AccNo2 for same values. Each column might consist of same values as multiple times. I want them to display only when matched. Can anyone help me out??
The output should be like

```
SB_AccNo    CLAIM INITATED  SB_AccNo1   CLAIM INITATED1 SB_AccNo2CLAIM INITATED2    
122000031730    1854.36    122000031730   1483.00         122000031730  371.00  
122000031730    4172.31    122000031730   3338.00         122000031730  834.00  
122000031730    5099.49    122000031730   4080.00         122000031730  1019.00 
122000069210    54.56      122000069210   11999.00        122000069210  3000.00 
122000069210    54.56      122000069210   21854.00        122000069210  5463.00 
122000069210    14998.50   122000070281   1091.00         122000070281  273.00  
122000069210    27317.25   122000070281   1091.00         122000070281  273.00  
122000070281    1363.50    122000070281   3818.00         122000070281  954.00  
122000070281    1363.50    122000070281   13090.00        122000070281  3272.00 
122000070281    4772.25    122000070281   16362.00        122000070281  4091.00 
122000070281    16362.00   122000070281   17453.00        122000070281  4363.00
```

Comment: Use a query where you `inner join` on SB_AccNo,SB_AccNo1 and SB_AccNo2.

Comment: Please be a bit more explicit in your expected result. Based on this sample data, what do you want your query to return? Is the data stored in the same, or separate tables?

Comment: Erik von Asmuth They r stored in same table and i want columns SB_AccNo1 and SB_AccNo2 to be matched with column SB_AccNo. Column SB_AccNo may consist of repeated values too.

Comment: Gustav,  Tried Inner join too but as  SB_AccNo consists of multiple same values, the result I get is irrelevently repeated data.

Comment: So if fields `SB_AccNo`, `SB_AccNo1` and `SB_AccNo2` _on the same record_ match then display `Claim Initiated`, `Claim Initiated 1` and `Claim Initiated 2`?

Comment: Darren Bartrup-Cook Yes!! I want to display them.

Comment: Perhaps you should post example data in the actual table structure. If these are columns of same table, then show that, as well as example of desired output.

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it you need something like this SQL.
Just check if each of the values match in the `WHERE` clause.

```
 SELECT   SB_AccNo, [CLAIM INITATED]
        , SB_AccNo1, [CLAIM INITATED1]
        , SB_AccNo2, [CLAIM INITATED2]
 FROM   MyTable
 WHERE  SB_AccNo = SB_AccNo1 AND
        SB_AccNo = SB_AccNo2 AND 
        SB_AccNo1 = SB_AccNo2
```

**Edit:** Have added field names to SQL.
Are you sure it's INITATED and not INITIATED?

Comment: Hi Darren Bartrup-Cook, thanQ for the solution but it isnt working. I have already tried it. And sorry for the spelling mistake.

Comment: _It isn't working_ doesn't really help figure out the problem.  How is it not working?  You've confirmed that the three `AccNo` fields should be the same on the same record to display the `CLAIM INITATED` and that all the data is in the same table..... so what's missing?

Comment: I tried that solution earlier too but it ended up without any output. I don't know what is the problem. All three columns SB_AccNo,SB_AccNo1 and SB_AccNo2 consists of repeated data in them. I think it is the problem.

Comment: ok, so it's not showing an error message.  Just not returning any records.  Are the fields in the table the same type... that'd return a `data type mismatch` error though.  Any hidden values in the field - carriage returns, new line breaks?  Increase the height of your records is there a second line of text in a record?

Comment: Nope! its not showing any error. Yes the fields are of same types and some times repeated in a single column as I have shown above in the table.